# Dart doc comment escape square brackets

Tags: dart, comments

I have a simple enum with a doc comment wanting to display [] inside the comment:

```
/// Define the brackets used when displaying a `List` in a cell.
///
/// Supported bracket types are:
/// * parentheses: ()
/// * curly: {}
/// * square: []
enum ListBrackets {
  /// Use parentheses
  parentheses,
  /// Use curly brackets
  curly,
  /// Use square brackets
  square;
}
```

However all i get is:
`Define the brackets used when displaying a List in a cell. Supported bracket types are: parentheses: () curly: {} square:`

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the square brackets with a `\`:

```dart
/// Define the brackets used when displaying a `List` in a cell.
///
/// Supported bracket types are:
/// * parentheses: ()
/// * curly: {}
/// * square: \[\]
enum ListBrackets {
  /// Use parentheses
  parentheses,
  /// Use curly brackets
  curly,
  /// Use square brackets
  square;
}
```

(You could also only escape the first one: `\[]` but I prefer to escape both!)

Comment: Then i get this: ``square: \\``

Comment: @jksevend I'm testing it in https://dartpad.dev/ and I get square: []

Comment: hmm maybe intellij has an error